# AttributeError: 'Doctype' object has no attribute 'has_attr'

Tags: python, hyperlink, attributes

The script is suppose to extract all hyperlinks

```
  import httplib2
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.nytimes.com')

for link in bs.BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link['href'])
```

This produces the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Doctype' object has no attribute 'has_attr'
```

How do i correct this, i've looked everywhere else couldnt find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be parser-related, as it is manifested only with `lxml` parser (which is default on many systems). Using stock `html.parser` solves it:

```
for link in bs.BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser',
                             parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link['href'])
```